# Django model method being called twice on production, but not on staging or local dev server

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

My stack:

- Ubuntu 18
- Postgres 10
- Gunicorn
- NGINX
- Django 2.1

I have a Django model method that sends an email to users if a form is submitted in a view.

After deploying an update lastnight that didn't touch any of the code in the app described below, as of this morning when that form is submitted the method that sends the email is being called twice, leading to two duplicate emails being sent each time.

I've started logging the tracebacks of the calls that lead to this method being called using `stack_info=True` and they are identical for both calls of this method (i.e.  it's the method is not being called by rogue code in different places each time) a couple of hundred milliseconds apart.

The logged calls are both like:

```
File "/home/[path]/views.py", line 292, in my_view
    foo': _foo})
File "/home/[path]/views.py", line 231, in _process_view_helper_func
    thing.send_email()
File "/home/[path]/models.py", line 351, in send_email
    stack_info=True,
```

The confusing thing is that when I submit the form locally (Django dev server) and on my staging server (same stack and configuration as production server) the method is only called once and no duplicate emails are sent.

What could be causing my Production server to be calling this method twice, but not my Staging or local dev server?

Comment: Is it an AJAX request? Could JavaScript be making the same request twice in production?

Comment: Is `send_email()` called twice or is the entire view being called twice? Can you check your access logs to see if the request is made twice?

Comment: Is this method being called in a GET request? Clients can sometimes perform two parallel requests (I never understood why), but I've had this problem before. Here is a useful question on the subject: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server If it's a POST, please ignore this comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions all, to answer in order:

Alasdair - Nope not an AJAX request, the method is triggered from a standard Django form POST

dirkgroten - From the logged tracebacks it looks like the entire view is being called twice with identical POSTs from the form.

Augusto Men - While the view can be GET-ed, the code that calls the helper function that eventually calls the email method is behind `form.is_valid()`, so can only be triggered by a valid POST.